# How change the column type numeric to enum in sparkling water using scala?

Tags: scala, h2o, sparkling-water

I have to change numeric columns to Enum type of h2o frame in sparkling water using Scala and how to print schema of h2o frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to transform our H2OFrame.

Here is an example:

```
NameOfH2OFrame.colToEnum(Array(<"NameOfColumnYouWantToChangeInEnum">))

val h2oFrameTrain = h2oContext.asH2OFrame(trainingData)
h2oFrameTrain.colToEnum(Array("WEEKDAY_LABEL", "EVENT_TYPE", "EVENT_NAME"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toCategoricalVec`

Here is an example of the usage:

```
val trainFrame:H2OFrame = bigTable
withLockAndUpdate(trainFrame){ fr => fr.replace(19, fr.vec("IsDepDelayed").toCategoricalVec)}
```